# Loop create new dataframes

Tags: r

I have 10 different regression models called "regression1" , "regression2", etc along with their corresponding standard errors called "standarderrors1", "standarderrors2", etc. For each model I am trying to create a new dataframe only containing the coefficients and the confidence interval with the below formula using a loop:

```
for(i in 1:10){
betas <- regression[[i]]$coefficients
upper_bound <- betas + z_score*standerrors[[i]]
lower_bound <- betas - z_score*standerrors[[i]]

assign(paste0("DF",i), data.frame(betas))
assign(paste0("plot",i))$upper <- upper_bound
assign(paste0("plot",i))$lower <- lower_bound}
```

This first part works well but I am struggling to use the loop to create the new dataframes and add variables, as I keep getting the error "target of assignment expands to non-language object".

Any help on how to create the 10 new dataframes with the loop would be super appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is essential to share a reproducible piece of your data with `dput(head(data))` so you will have better chances on getting relevant answers.

Comment: Hi Anoushiravan, thanks for your feedback. If I share a reproducible piece of my data I would have to reproduce all the process of creating the equations with the separate clustered standard errors which may make the question unnecessarily complicated. I am happy to add it if it helps but my only doubt is as to the syntax to create new dataframes within a loop (I just updated the question to make it more clear). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following -

```
for(i in 1:10){
  betas <- regression[[i]]$coefficients
  upper_bound <- betas + z_score*standerrors[[i]]
  lower_bound <- betas - z_score*standerrors[[i]]
  
  assign(paste0("DF",i), data.frame(betas))
  assign(paste0("plot",i), data.frame(upper = upper_bound, lower = lower_bound))
}
```

However, note that it is not a good practice to create lot of dataframes in global environment. They are difficult to manage and pollutes the global environment. Consider using lists instead.

Comment: Thank you very much Ronak, this is very useful! Would you know how could I modify your code so that the lower bound is added to the same dataframe as the upper bound, instead of creating a 3rd dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

To have some data, as suggested by Anoushiravan R, would help people help you to find the best solution, that may require e.g. data reshaping. Also, as suggested Ronak Shah, work with lists may be more tidy and efficient. Here is a solution based on the `tidy` function in the package `broom` and using the `map` function from the package `purrr` (I am loading all of the tidyverse package).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
models <- list(
  m1 <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width, data=iris),
  m2 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, data=iris)
)

dfs <- map(models, ~tidy(.x)) %>% 
  map(~mutate(.x, lci = estimate-1.96*std.error, uci = estimate+1.96*std.error))
```

Now you have a list `dfs` containing a dataframe for each of the models.

Comment: Thank you Claudio, I will try to amend and use lists instead.